# How to skip a line on python IF=== statement?

Tags: python-2.7

How do I skip #Bitcoin to spend if I chose 2 and go to #Coin to buy or sell?

```
#Bittrex Buy and Sell
choice=float(raw_input("Enter 1 Buy, 2 Sell :       "))
if (choice!=1):
    if (choice!=2): 
        sys.exit('Choice number {0} not valid. Please enter 1 to Buy or 2 to Sell'.format(choice))

#Bitcoin to spend
bitcoin=float(raw_input("Bitcoin to Spend: "))

#Market to trade at
trade = 'BTC'

#Coint to Buy
currency = raw_input("Coin: ")
```

Comment: You fix the indentation or add one more if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not how I would do it, this a cleaner way to handle the approach your going after.

```
#Bittrex Buy and Sell
choice=float(raw_input("Enter 1 Buy, 2 Sell :       "))
if choice not in [1,2]:
    sys.exit('Choice number {0} not valid. Please enter 1 to Buy or 2 to Sell'.format(choice))

if choice == 1:
    #Bitcoin to spend
    bitcoin=float(raw_input("Bitcoin to Spend: "))

if choice == 2:
    #Coint to Buy
    currency = raw_input("Coin: ")

#Market to trade at
trade = 'BTC'
```